# Proof about bijective linear transformation and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear algebra final exam next wednesday, and I still couldn't think of the proof. I don't usually  paste the proposition and ask people to solve it for me, but I really have done almost nothing for this proof.

Anyways, the proposition is this.

> Let $V \leq R^n$, $W \leq R^m$ subspaces. If there exists a bijective (i.e 1-1 and onto) linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$, then $\dim V = \dim W$.

I tried to do my proof by contradiction, but it didn't go well. (I'm actually not sure if I'm even able to use contradiction in this proof.)

Any hints that you can give to me?

Comment: Injective linear maps map linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets, and surjective linear maps map spanning sets to spanning sets. Bijective linear maps therefore preserve bases, and hence dimension. It's worth trying to prove these claims for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a huge help to me. I should be getting used to these 'proving' maths...but its difficult for me.....

Comment: No problem! Just beware of leaving maths to the last minute; since it builds upon itself, it's really important to address holes in your understanding as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

You don't need a proof by contradiction. Use that an injective linear map $f:V\longrightarrow W$ maps a basis  $\mathcal B(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ of $V$ onto a basis $\mathcal B'=f(\mathcal B)=\bigl(f(e_1),\dots,f(e_n)\bigr)$ of the subspace $f(V)$.